# How to get a specific column when queried with certain data. (There are 'n' similar columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have *n* similar columns (x1, x2, x3,... xn) in a record. I want to get the columns that have a value '5'. How could this be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us what u have tried so far, it's preety simple thought.

Comment: Get the names of the columns that have '5'? And can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I need to search for 99 columns but here is a sample of 5 records that I tried,

SELECT x1, x2, x3, x4, a
FROM tablename
WHERE (x1 = '5' OR x2= '5' OR x3= '5' OR x4 = '5')
AND a = '89911';
--'a' being a primary key

Comment: Having columns name `x1`, `x2`, ... usually indicates a bad database design. A SQL statement always has a fixed set of columns (for all rows!). So you cannot create a query that returns different columns each time you run it or has different columns for each row. You should really rethink your design and try to normalize it.

Answer (score 0):

From your vague description, I think you just need a simple WHERE clause.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name(s) =5;
```

Comment: This would certainly work. But the problem here is, I have 99 similar columns namely, x1, x2... x99. Is there anything that could be done to save typing effort?

Comment: @newuser No, one simpler method is to use Alias. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... etc
FROM example
WHERE column1 = 5 or column2 = 5 or column3 = 5 etc...;
```

next time, it will be better if u ask a question + show what u have tried.

Comment: I need to search for 99 columns but here is a sample of 5 records that I tried,

SELECT x1, x2, x3, x4, a
FROM tablename
WHERE (x1 = '5' OR x2= '5' OR x3= '5' OR x4 = '5')
AND a = '89911';
--'a' being a primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+'=5 or ' ,'') + name FROM sys.columns where object_name(object_id)='tablename' order by name SELECT @listStr
```

The above sql shall get all the column names from 'your table' and give you the list in the results window. Once executed, I believe its self explanatory.